# AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'groupyby'

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

Having used pandas for a long time, this is the first time I got an error as shown in the title of this question and I'm stuck because I don't see any reason why the DataFrame would not have the groupby function "available." Already reinstalled pandas, even looked in the code that is being used (groupby is defined in the core modules).

This is what I'm doing, the error is shown below:

```
def _bin_by_answer(row):
    collocated_answer = row['colname']
    if collocated_answer <= -1:
        return -1
    elif collocated_answer >= 1:
        return 1
    else:
        return 0

df = pd.read_pickle(somepath)
df['binned'] = df.apply(func=lambda row: _bin_by_answer(row), axis=1)
df_sampled = df.groupyby(by='binned', group_keys=False).apply(lambda grp: grp.sample(n=50))
```

Here is the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Users/felix/IdeaProjects/cope/ann4class/exportfromaestoretomturk.py", line 858, in <module>
process_and_export_ps2_inductive()
File "/Users/felix/IdeaProjects/cope/ann4class/exportfromaestoretomturk.py", line 786, in process_and_export_ps2_inductive
df_sampled = df_results.groupyby(by=COL_ANSWER1_COLLOCATED_MAJORITY, group_keys=False).apply(
    File "/Users/felix/anaconda3/envs/cope/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py", line 5179, in __getattr__
return object.__getattribute__(self, name)
AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'groupyby'
```

Comment: You typed `groupyby` instead of `groupby`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As suggested by ddoGas, the cause of this error was a typo. So, I guess the general answer would be: In case you're reading this question because you're running into a similar problem, double check that you wrote the function name correctly.